# Android: Numeric keypad - how to add numbers to an interger

Tags: java, android, button, integer

I'm new to developing in general so apologies for the probably very basic question but I just can't work it out!

I'm trying to setup a numeric keypad within my app (somewhat like a calculator). It has buttons for numbers 0-9 and a EditText field to display the number created.

Essentially I have no idea how to go about making the numbers join each other to create multiple digits.
Ie, when you push '1' and then '2' the integer 12 is created and so on. All I managed to do is get them to add (push 1 then 2 and creates 3).

I know it's vague question without code to show, I really just need to be told what I need to look into for this.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Ultimately I need to end up with an integer not a String so that the value can be used later.

Comment: If you need to end up with an int, perhaps you should look into `Integer.parseInt(String s)`

Comment: Are you asking a coding question or math question? 
`a*10+b` is your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Represent each digit as a String.
2. When a number is pressed, perform a string concatenation with the previous 
   number.
3. When all numbers are entered, simply convert the string (stringOfNumbers) to an integer (or whatever data type is needed). i.e.:

   ```
    CharSequence s;
    stringOfNumbers= Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
   ```

Comment: Got it!

Thanks a lot for this.

I'm not sure if it's a mistake in your code or just in the particular situation I was in, but I had to put the integer I wanted to create from the String at the start of the code at part 3.

So: 

'newInteger = Integer.parseInt(stringOfNumbers);'

I didn't need any of the CharSequence/toString parts.

Comment: Ok, perfect, Josh! Also, please do not forget to uproot my solution and check it as the accepted solution.